# Only able to get the answerID of oldest post instead of post that is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, frontend

I'm using firebase to create a collection of questions and sub-collection of answers. I've been able to render the collection and sub-collection successfully with react. The issue happens when I'm trying to grab the ID of a post from firebase in order to reference it so a user can edit or delete answers. For some reason it always grabs the oldest post's ID.

Here is some of the functionality code in order to give a better picture:

```
function Post({
  answers,
  questionId,
  question,
  timestamp,
  buildFaastUser,
  category,
  }) 
{
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");

  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleAnswer = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (user) {
      db.collection("questions")
        .doc(questionId)
        .collection("answer")
        .add({
          questionId: questionId,
          timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          answer: answer,
          user: {
            displayName: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            uid: user.uid,
          },
        });
    }
    setOpenModal(false);
  };

  const handleDeletePost = (answerId) => {
    console.log("id", answerId);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleAnswerMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };


  const answerMenuId = "primary-answer-account-menu";
  const answerRenderMenu = (answerId) => (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
      id={answerMenuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Edit</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem
        onClick={handleMenuClose}
        onClick={() => handleDeletePost(answerId)}
      >
        {console.log(answerId)}
        Delete
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );
```

Here is the JSX code for where it's implemented:

```
return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post__info">
        <Avatar src={buildFaastUser ? buildFaastUser.photo : Avatar} />
        <h5>
          {buildFaastUser.displayName
            ? buildFaastUser.displayName
            : buildFaastUser.email}
        </h5>
        <small>{new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toLocaleString()}</small>
        <small>{category}</small>
      </div>
      <div className="post__body">
        <div className="post__question">
          <p>{question}</p>
          <Modal...
        </div>

        <div className="post__answer">
          {answers.map(
            ({ answer, answerId, questionId: qId, timestamp, user }) => (
              <p
                key={answerId}
                style={{ position: "relative", paddingBottom: "20px" }}
              >
                {questionId === qId ? (
                  <span>
                    <span
                      style={{
                        marginTop: "20px",
                        color: "black",
                        fontSize: "medium",
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        display: "flex",
                        textDecorationLine: "underline",
                        paddingBottom: "10px",
                      }}
                    >
                      {user.displayName ? user.displayName : user.email}{" "}
                      answered on{" "}
                      {new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toLocaleString()}
                      <br />
                      <div className="post__answerMenu">
                        <IconButton
                          edge="end"
                          aria-label="post options"
                          aria-controls={answerMenuId}
                          aria-haspopup="true"
                          onClick={handleAnswerMenuOpen}
                          color="inherit"
                        >
                          <MoreVertIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        {answerRenderMenu(answerId)}
                      </div>
                    </span>
                    {parse(answer)}
                    <br />
                    <span
                      style={{
                        position: "absolute",
                        color: "gray",
                        fontSize: "small",
                        display: "flex",
                        right: "0px",
                      }}
                    ></span>
                  </span>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
              </p>
            )
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="post__questionAnswer">
        <Button onClick={() => setOpenModal(true)} className="post__btnAnswer">
          Answer
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I suspect the issue is how the answerId is referenced but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was the last document id for the answers database in firebase was being grabbed as it was being looped through.

So the solution here was to create a component for each answer within the posts.

```
    return (
    <div className="post__answer">
      {answers.map(
        ({ answer, answerId, questionId: qId, timestamp, user }) => (
          <AnswerItem
            answer={answer}
            answerId={answerId}
            answerQuestionId={qId}
            questionId={questionId}
            timestamp={timestamp}
            user={user}
          />
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

That solved it.